# Decorator to take away repetitive code

Tags: python, django

I'm using django and I wrote this decorator to take away some of the repetitive code I found for ajax views and I want to know your opinion (too basic, bad design, try this instead, etc).

```
def ajax_only(func):
    def _ajax_only(request,*args,**kwargs):
        if not request.is_ajax():
            return HttpResponse('<p>Ajax not supported.</p>')
        else:
            return func(request,*args,**kwargs)
    return _ajax_only
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You should use the functools.wraps function, it makes sure the docstring/name/etc gets passed through
2. Instead of "ajax not supported" shouldn't it be: "only ajax supported"?
3. Shouldn't you respond with a Status Code 400 or something if not using ajax when you should be
4. Why do you want to check this? What's the point of enforcing ajax calls, won't that just make testing harder?

Comment: thanks for the comment. For 2, i meant "ajax not supported by the browser", for 3 i've got just one handler function that receive's the response for the server, with a 400 code i would need to create a separate function to handle that type of response.

Comment: @user1108631, your test only checks whether the current request is AJAX, it tells you nothing about whether the browser supports it. You don't need to handle the 400 response, it means the request was incorrectly made to the server.

Answer (score 1):

It might be not exactly what you need, but have a look at [annoying "ajax_request" decorator](https://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/src/a0de8b294db3/annoying/decorators.py#cl-150).